# scala: how to update super class attributes

Tags: scala

I am new to *scala* and have problem to update attributes.

I have a class that inherits from an abstract class as follows:

```
abstract class A(x:type1,y:type1){
     val z:Option[type1]= None
     def void:type2 
} 

class B extends A(x,y){ 
     def this(x:type1,y:type1,z_:type1)= {this(x,y) val z=Some(z_)}
     def void:type2 = ??? 
}
```

If I call  `new B(test,test,test)` it doesn't update the value of `z` which remains `None` all the time.

What is the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With val you create immutable fields/variables. Declaring another one in the subclass. If you want to update it use var, in the superclass and assignment in the subclass. This should work:

```
abstract class A(x:type1,y:type1){
     var z:Option[type1]= None
     def void:type2 
} 

class B extends A(x,y){ 
     def this(x:type1,y:type1,z_:type1)= {this(x,y) z=Some(z_)}
     def void:type2 = ??? 
}
```